# Get size of the file located in iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, filesize

Is there a way to get the `filSize` attribute of the **original** file that is not been downloaded yet?
I've got the `fileURL` with `UIDocumentPickerViewController` and then I'm trying to check the `fileSize` but it seems it's just an alias to the original file that's not downloaded yet. And the size isn't correct.

```
debugPrint("size: ", try? fileURL.resourceValues(forKeys: [.fileSizeKey, .ubiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey]))
```

```
"fileURL: " file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Downloads/.vvvvv.mp4.icloud
"size: " Optional(Foundation.URLResourceValues(_values: [__C.NSURLResourceKey(_rawValue: NSURLUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey): NSURLUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusNotDownloaded, __C.NSURLResourceKey(_rawValue: NSURLFileSizeKey): 340], _keys: Set([__C.NSURLResourceKey(_rawValue: NSURLUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey), __C.NSURLResourceKey(_rawValue: NSURLFileSizeKey)])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
func getFileSize(fileURL: URL?) -> Int64? {
    guard let fileURL,
          fileURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource(),
          let fileAttributes = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: fileURL.path),
          let fileSizeInBytes = fileAttributes[.size] as? Int64 else {
        return nil
    }

    fileURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()

    return fileSizeInBytes
}
```